# Retrieving data from IBM DB2 using pyodbc and the related error

Tags: python-3.x, linux, db2, odbc

I confirm that I have gone through multiple posts in StackOverflow with respect to similar problem, still stuck with the below problem, hence posting to seek guidance/pointers.

Following is the code

```py
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

conn_str = 'DRIVER={' + config['db2']['driver'] + '};' \
            + 'SERVER=' + config['db2']['server'] + ';' \
            + 'DATABASE=' + config['db2']['database'] + ';' \
            + 'UID=' + config['db2']['uid'] + ';' \
            + 'PWD=' + config['db2']['password']
print(conn_str)

connection = pyodbc.connect(
    conn_str
)

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM schema.table_name LIMIT 2')
for row in cur:
    print (row)
```

Output from code execution

```
[connect string output]
DRIVER={'IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit'};SERVER='hostname';DATABASE='database';UID='userid';PWD='password'
```

```
[error from executing the code]
raise Error(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified')
```

Configuration file

```
$ cat config.ini
[db2]
driver = 'IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit'
server = 'hostname'
database = 'database'
uid = 'userid'
password = 'password'
```

Output of ODBC installer and uninstaller command

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/useradmin/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

```
cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[PostgreSQL]
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage=1

[MySQL]
Description=ODBC for MySQL
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage=1

[IBM i Access ODBC Driver]
Description=IBM i Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
Driver64=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading=0
DontDLClose=1
UsageCount=1

[IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit]
Description=IBM i Access for Linux 64-bit ODBC Driver
Driver=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading=0
DontDLClose=1
UsageCount=1
```

```
$ cat ~/.odbc.ini
[db2]
Driver          = IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit
DATABASE        = 'database'
SYSTEM          = hostname
HOSTNAME        = hostname
PORT            = 446
PROTOCOL        = TCPIP
```

```
$ isql db2 $username $password -v
[08001][unixODBC][IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]The specified database can not be accessed at this time.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I have double checked and confirm that there is no typo with driver name "IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit"

OS information
**x86_64 GNU/Linux**

Any pointers/guidance on how to debug the issue, please?

Comment: Your question does not show contents of your `/home/useradmin/.odbc.ini'` . That file should define your data source name (s) (DSN) and link them with the relevant driver, and give the dbname, hostname, poortnumber.  At the bash command line,  using the `isql` command, are you able to connect to the same data source with a userid and password? The command is similar to `isql -v $yourDSN $yourUser $yourPassword`  (where you substitute the variables by your own values).  If this command fails, please edit your question to add the full text, and also show your .odbc.ini file contents

Comment: Are you using the Linux system to access Db2 on IBM i? Or is everything on Linux? How do you address the Db2 server, which hostname and port?

Comment: @mao Earlier no configuration was added to ***~/.odbc.ini*** added now and ran it again. Output of isql command added to the original question.

Comment: @data_henrik Everything is on Linux. Added configuration to ***~/.odbc.ini***

Comment: In your .odbc.ini, are you certain that the the hostname, and databasename values are correct ?  Additionally on linux (which distro ?) have you opened the port 446 in the software firewall for tcp inbound and outbound traffic ?   Understand that until isql connects, then python cannot connect, that's the reason for working with isql first.  On the i-series, the command `DSPRDBDIRE` will show the database name.

Comment: The database name may also be the same as the system name, and you may additionally need to specify the library list in the odbc.ini.

Comment: @mao Yes, am sure the hostname and database name are definitely correct. I just masked the value before posting it. Also, am able to connect to the server from DBeaver GUI tool.  jdbc url used in the GUI tool
***jdbc:as400://servername;libraries=databasename;***
but the DBeaver installed in windows uses jt400.jar via jdbc.

Tried modifying system/database to 
***jdbc:as400://servername;libraries=databasename;*** (or)
***servername;libraries=databasename;***

Error is either database cannot be accessed or communication link failure.

Comment: @madmatrix, from linux bash shell can you ping the as400 by hostname and IP-address?  Which distro?  Did you open port 446 for tcp inbound and outbound traffic?

Comment: @mao
Yes, I confirm that ping is working fine with hostname and IP address. Also, port:446 is opened for tcp inbound and outbound traffic.
Distro: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Comment: In  .odbc.ini, ensure the database name is in UPPERCASE. jdbc and CLI do not share code so behave differently. You may have a downlevel PTF problem, at the i-series side and/or on the linux side. Verify your i access software is at the latest service level for its version. Verify the PTF level of the i-series is also at the latest for its release. Your question has missing version facts for either i-series or i access software on linux. Is this RHEL, SUSE, ubuntu, debian etc (which distro). This is likely a config problem you should open a ticket with IBM if you cannot progress here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the schema name with the database name.
Odds are you can omit the database name completely (or leave it empty string and let it default to *SYSBAS). Instead, you can specify the DefaultLibraries argument.

See the IBM doc [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=details-connection-string-keywords) for info on the valid connection string (and odbc.ini) keywords.

Similarly, you can omit the `PORT`, `PROTOCOL`, and HOSTNAME keywords, as they're not supported by this driver.

That will leave you with an `odbc.ini` that looks as simple as this:

```
[db2]
Driver           = IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit
DefaultLibraries = 'database'
SYSTEM           = hostname
```